# UNIX homework question regarding piping output, I don't understand what it's asking?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Basically, I need to come up with a command that sends the contents of a file `xxx` into a program `yyy`, then the output is piped to the input of another program `zzz`, where the output is appended to a file `xyz`.

Comment: Pipe shell, command substitution and shell redirection is all you need.

Comment: Do you not understand what it's asking for, or do you just not know how to do it?

Comment: english is not my native language, i am confused what it is asking for

Comment: So are you asking for help to comprehend the question, or to come up with the command?

Comment: This is just sad; it should be retagged [tag:kali] and be done with it. *Sic transit gloria mundi*

Answer (score 7):

Always try and break things down into there simplest steps, then try and put things together after. To start the first part, I'd construct myself a sample file.

```
$ echo -e "line 1 ABA\nline 2 ABB\nline 3 CCC\n" > xxx
$ cat xxx 
line 1 ABA
line 2 ABB
line 3 CCC
```

So now we have file `xxx`. Now we need to use something that can act as program `yyy`. Unix is full of commands that can fill in as stand ins for this, so let's just pick `grep` for now. Grep will find strings that we tell it we're looking for so let's tell it to find strings that contain "AB".

```
$ cat xxx | grep AB
line 1 ABA
line 2 ABB
```

So we've just fulfilled the first 2 requirements.

- `cat xxx` sends the contents of file `xxx`.
- `cat xxx | grep AB` sends the contents to a program, `yyy`.

So the next bit, "pipe the output to the input of another program `zzz`", should be fairly straightforward too, since it's more of the same, of what we've been doing with a command like `grep`. So let's use another `grep` like so:

```
$ cat xxx | grep AB | grep BB
line 2 ABB
```

Great, we're almost there. We've just completed the 3rd requirement.

- `cat xxx | grep AB | grep BB` take the output from `grep AB` as input, and generates its own output.

So the last bit, we just need to append the output from `zzz`, i.e. `grep BB`. That's easy. If you notice how we constructed the initial file, `xxx`, we used a file redirection `>` which will take the output from a command and dump it into a file. The redirector, `>` will overwrite a file with content, even if it already exists. But we need to append. Luckily we can make use of another redirector, `>>`. This will append the output from a command to a file that already exists.

Speaking of already existing, we need to construct file `xyz`. So let's use our `echo` method we used to make `xxx`.

```
$ echo -e "previous line 1\nprevious line 2" > xyz
$ cat xyz 
previous line 1
previous line 2
```

Now let's append the output from our command we've been constructing:

```
$ cat xxx | grep AB | grep BB >> xyz
```

We can check our results:

```
$ cat xyz 
previous line 1
previous line 2
line 2 ABB
```

And we're done.

Comment: I wasn't expecting much from help, but THANK YOU mister. much better than professor lecture note

Comment: You're welcome. Take this as an example and see if you can make up your own version. Try and make it more elaborate with more lines of text. You can also use commands such as `seq 50 | grep ^3` to generate the contents of file `xxx` too. We are in the chat room here if you need additional guidance, feel free to stop by.

Comment: @DacAsf, Glad your issue got resolved. Please accept the answer and be sure to ask more questions if you have issues :)